# Difference between using a loop and multiplying using scalar

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

My title may not have been properly formatted but, we took a class on plotting 3D mesh and surfaces and were taught the first method below which multiplied using scalars to obtain `'z'`. Upon searching for a solution to a problem I found another method in obtaining `'z'`. Upon plotting you get visually similar surfaces but, their directions are different hence values used.

I want to know the difference between the two.

**Method 1**

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.1:2);
Z = X.*exp(-((X-Y.^2).^2 + Y.^2));
mesh(X,Y,Z),xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z' )
```

**Method 2**

```
m = 1;
for X = -2:0.1:2
    n = 1;
    for Y = -2:0.1:2
        Z(m,n) = X.*exp(-((X-Y^2)^2 + Y^2));
        n = n + 1;
    end 
    m = m + 1;
end 

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.1:2);
mesh(X,Y,Z),xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
```

Comment: reverse the loop order in method 2 (first Y, then X) and it will give you the same result. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvbngts-1) states that `[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z) returns 3-D grid coordinates defined by the vectors x, y, and z. The grid represented by X, Y, and Z has size length(y)-by-length(x)-by-length(z).`

Comment: thanks very much, it works